# Running PHP files will not load but instead download

Tags: php

I'm trying to run a php info file but it will not work properly. When I run the file through the browser(Firefox), it will ask me to download instead of displaying content. What do you reccomend? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you get when you point your browser at http://localhost?

Comment: I have a bunch of files there. Web server works good. I can code fine but the php will not work :)

Comment: When I run the this command: cat /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Sun Jun 25 07:35:02.934581 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7172] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jun 25 07:35:02.934639 2017] [core:notice] [pid 7172] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

Do you think this has anything to do with it?

Comment: What output do you get when you run `a2enmod php7.0` (as root)? (I'm assuming you're running 16.04?)

Comment: Please enable the `php7.0` module with the command given by rkhff

Comment: I ran that command and it says: ERROR: Module 7.0 does not exist!


I don't know how to make it exist :(

Comment: I'm running:DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Comment: I also did this: sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0

That didn't help either.

Comment: Quick question: sudo is the same as root right?

Comment: After running a2enmmod php7.0 I got this error:
Considering conflict php5 for php7.0:
Module php7.0 already enabled
How do I fix that problem?

Comment: You could try to uninstall php5.0 first using `sudo apt purge php5.0 && sudo apt autoremove`

Comment: Done, it says: E: Unable to locate package php5.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php5.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php5.0'

I must have removed it after post. I actually did about 1000 things by now and nothing yet :)

Answer (score 0):

I started by purging php7 and reinstalling. When that didn't work I purged apache2 and php7 and reinstalled.

sudo apt-get purge php7.0-common

sudo apt-get purge php7.*

sudo apt autoremove

apt-get purge apache2

sudo apt autoremove

sudo apt-get install apache2 php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload

sudo /etc/init.d/php7.0-fpm reload

I still get this message "Considering conflict php5 for php7.0:" but at least it's working now.